# Does iphone mobile chrome, firefox and opera browser support FCM web notification?

Tags: browser, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried web notification subscription in android and desktop using different browser like chrome, Firefox and opera using Firebase Cloud Messaging Client.

Same thing i checked in iphone mobile chrome, firefox and opera browser but it is not working. 
When site load not in iphone chrome, firefox and opera browser not showing notification permission dialog only.

Can any one tell me wheather browser notification is supported in iphone chrome, firefox and opera browser?

Answer (score 1):

afaik iPhone does not support push notification in any browser.